# How do I find an index or mutual fund?

Tags: mutual-funds, index-fund, world

I am thinking about investing for the first time. How can I search for a fund within a certain industry?

Comment: Can you add a country tag. Most countries would have standard sites that would list popular funds.

Comment: Index funds are (generally) a specific investment approach of a mutual fund, which is the more general term. So the question breaks down into two parts: First, how to find mutual funds which are available to you; Second, how to determine whether a given mutual fund is an index fund (if it is not obvious from the name). I suggest breaking your question into two accordingly, in addition to adding the country tag that Dheer suggests.

Comment: @dheer I was thinking worldwide

Comment: I added the tag "world"

Answer (score 1):

Index funds [aim to generate the same rate of return as an underlying market index](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/index-investing.asp).  Tracking a certain industry would expose you to risks specific to that industry and likely not be a good approach.
If you happen to be in Canada, [The Canadian Couch Potato](http://canadiancouchpotato.com/recommended-funds/) gives several recommendations for index investors and has many other informative articles.

Comment: I was planning to buy a lot of different funds so that I can protect myself through diversification. I want to specifically invest in vaping because I believe it will be popular. I want to specifically invest about 5% of my money in fund that deals with vaping companies. I will check out the site.

Comment: okay, that really isn't an index-based approach though :)  You're betting on a very small segment of the market where as index-investing is a slow-and-steady approach that follows the general trend of a whole market to increase over longer time spans.